# How to fix Visual Studio co_await error / squiggle?

Tags: visual-studio, c++-winrt

I get red squiggles and the error

> `E1776: function "winrt::impl::notify_awaiter<T>::notify_awaiter(const winrt::impl::notify_awaiter<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction> &) [with T=winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction]" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function`

wherever I use `co_await` in my C++/WinRT project.

---

Here is a picture of the squiggle, it happens on every `co_await` in the code:

[image]

---

I am using `Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (17.0.4)` and compile the project with `/std:c++latest`. It compiles and runs fine!

Is that squiggle expected behavior? Can I fix the issue somehow?

Comment: That appears to be a [known issue](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/declared-implicitly-cannot-be-referenc/1203236). After much [discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/753) it has come apparent that it is an IntelliSense issue. No solutions to this day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`co_await` support has been landed in VS2022 and planned for VS2019 according to https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/declared-implicitly-cannot-be-referenc/1203236#TPIN-N10036664

- Visual Studio 2022 version 17.2.0: ✅
- Visual Studio 2019 version 16.11.14: ❌